# Libre Office - merge sheets

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In one file I have two sheets, which share some of the columns. I'd need to merge the sheets based on column name, if the column does not exist, add it. Ie. I have

Sheet 1

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | description  |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | name1 | description1 |
|  2 | name2 | description2 |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Sheet 2

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| id | name  | description  | title  |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
|  3 | name3 | description3 | title3 |
|  4 | name4 | description4 | title4 |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Desired output

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| id | name  | description  | title  |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
|  1 | name1 | description1 |        |
|  2 | name2 | description2 |        |
|  3 | name3 | description3 | title3 |
|  4 | name4 | description4 | title4 |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would try googling `libre office merge sheets` or `libre office union sheets`. It gives quite promising results.

Comment: Can you copy and paste one table onto the end of the other, select all the data in both tables, then sort the table for ascending IDs?

Comment: I could, but I have many sheets and way more columns than in my example, so it would take really long to do this manually. I hoped to find some automated solution, but googling this didn't reveal anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this python + pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
a = glob.glob("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in a:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
print all_data
```

This will merge all the data from the location you specified and it will display